# What is the CLmax of the CF-100 Canuck?

Tags: aerodynamics, avro-cf-100

I've been struggling to find specifications for the [CF-100 Canuck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avro_Canada_CF-100_Canuck). What is the *CLmax* of the CF-100 Canuck and how can I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CF-100 had a symmetrical [NACA 0010 airfoil](https://1000aircraftphotos.com/HistoryBriefs/AvroCanadaCF100.htm), which had a Clmax of just under [1.4.](http://airfoiltools.com/airfoil/details?airfoil=naca0010-il) according to Airfoil Tools.com (Xfoil).  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah that's perfect thank you!